# Proving divisibility by 3

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need to prove that "m+n and mn are divisible by 3 if and only if m and n are divisible by 3. (where m,n ∈ Z).

The statement above takes the form of (P1 ^ P2) ⟺ Q which (assuming I proved this correctly) is logically equivalent to ((P1 ^ P2) ⟹ Q) ^ (Q ⟹ (P1 ^ P2)). I was already able to prove the backward direction, Q ⟹ (P1 ^ P2) but I still need to prove (P1 ^ P2) ⟹ Q). I'm having troubles with this since the premises, P1 and P2 are harder to work around with unlike Q ⟹ (P1 ^ P2) wherein the premise is simply "m and n are divisible by 3". Any help?

Additionally, I've tried using the contrapositive of the statement so I can use Q (or "not Q" rather) as the premise but I can't seem to make that work as well.

**Edit**: Alternative answers without modular arithmetic would be highly appreciated as we haven't touched upon that topic yet. Also, I simply need to prove "(P1 ^ P2) ⟹ Q)" which means I need to start my proof with "Suppose P1 and P2... then Q" (This was already answered in the comment section but it involved modulus).

For reference, I solved the backward direction like this:

Let m,n ∈ Z

Assume m and n are divisible by 3 (which is Q).
Then, m = 3a and n = 3b for some a,b ∈ Z. Thus, m + n = 3a + 3b = 3( a + b) where a + b ∈ Z. Therefore, m + n is divisible by 3.

(I pretty much did the same process for proving mn.)

I just need to prove "(P1 ^ P2) ⟹ Q)" using the same technique (without modulus involved).

**Edit:** Figured out some form of solution already. Thanks!

Comment: Yesterday you asked [this quesion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4095766/proving-divisibility-using-basic-proof-methods) which is essentially identical.  $3$ is slightly easier to handle then $5$ becausr there are fewer cases to check (assuming, that is, that you do not want to use any general results from arithmetic).

Comment: Do you already know Euclid's Lemma, i.e. if a prime divides a product then it divides some factor? Or do you know FTA = fund. thm. of arithmetic?

Comment: Please answer the prior question or else your question will likely be closed for lacking needed context.

Comment: Euclid's Lemma and FTA = I understand what they state but both haven't been formally taught yet in my current course so I'm not sure if I could include it in my proof.

Answer (score 2):

For $mn$ to be divisible by $3$, since $3$ is prime, $m$, $n$, or both variables have to be divisible by $3$. This is because since $3$ is prime, it has no other factors other than $1$ and itself. This means that $m$ or $n$ has to be $0$ $($mod $3)$. But, for $m + n$ to be divisible by $3$, $m + n = 0$ $($mod $3)$. But since we already know that either $m$ or $n$ has to be $0$ $($mod $3)$, the other variable also has to be $0$ mod $3$, because $0 + 0 = 0$. So, if and only if $m$ and $n$ are both divisible by $3$, then $m + n$ and $mn$ are divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative proof for one direction.

Suppose $m+n$ and $mn$ are divisible by $3$. Note that $m$ and $n$ are the roots of $x^2-(m+n)+mn=0$. Now, mod $3$, this equation is $x^2=0$, whose only solution is $x \equiv 0 \bmod 3$. Thus both $m$ and $n$ are divisible by $3$.

Comment: Is there another way to prove the statement without modulus involved? Unfortunately, we haven't touched upon that topic yet. Thank you!

Comment: @2043, sure, just write $x^2=(m+n)+mn$ and so $x^2$ is divisible by $3$ and so is $x$.

Comment: Likely unhelpful for OP = @2043 since if they don't already know $\,3\mid xy\Rightarrow 3\mid x\,$ or $\,3\mid y\,$ then they likely also don't  know the special case $\,y = x,\,$ i.e. $\,3\mid x^2\Rightarrow 3\mid x.\ $ And they already stated they don't know modular arithmetic.